# Interaction variables work differently when population is split

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, population, stratification

Let's say I have two predictors to predict financial risk: Gender and shopping habits. Gender has levels of "Male" and "Female", while shopping habits has "quick shopper" and "slow shopper".

I am quite surprised to see this: When I split the population into "male" and "female", shopping habits as a single variable work quite well to separate the risk on female population (not for males). This also intuitively makes sense. But when I create an interaction variable of "gender:shopping habits" and look at logistic regression, there is no risk separation whatsoever even on the dummy created "female:quick shopper".

Could there be an explanation of this?

**Note:** I should add that the initial working performance is cross-validated (not an overfitting result).

**Note2:** I edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: Interactions can be affected by the differences in the distributions of the respective variables. I'll try to find a source for this and post.

Comment: Please list the models that you are running. Which variables are in each?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo; I meant gender:shopping habits as the interaction variable. I edited the question.

Comment: Are there any other (ie control) regressors? And more importantly, how are you deciding that there is "no risk separation whatsoever"? Have you tried standardizing your variables to see if the result holds? I also suspect the underlying distributions could be the problem. Try some graphical diagnostics!

Comment: Are we talking about descriptive statements (coefficient of interaction is close to zero) or about inference about population effects (p values etc.)?

Comment: I've been fitting each single predictor against the response variable and calculating the Ginis of each single predictor. That includes the dummy predictors as well (since gender:shopping is a categorical predictor with 4 levels now >>> male:quick shopper, male:slow shopper, female:quick shopper, female:slow shopper).

I'll display more info tomorrow if not clear.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: might not apply** because the OP's mention of "age" was a mistake. Would only still apply if another "third" variable (besides shopping habits and financial risk, not counting gender) is changing in the model...

**Original answer**:

If you're including age as a predictor in the model as well (not just the interaction of age and shopping habits...which is a regression faux pas), age could could be mediating the relationship between shopping habits and financial risk in women. When a third variable fully mediates the relationship between two others, entering it alongside the first variable as a regressor in multiple regression predicting the second variable will wipe out the relationship between the first and second variable, because it explains all the same variance in the second variable that the first does, and then some (probably).

Full mediation is somewhat rare with such indirectly related constructs as age, shopping habits, and financial risk though, so I doubt this is really the case if you've represented your variables accurately. I'm mostly suggesting this to imply that you should make sure you include your main effects with the interaction, and consider the possibility of (at least partial) mediation or other consequences of including a stronger predictor in the model.

Comment: I am so sorry, it's a typo; I meant gender:shopping habits as the interaction variable. I edited the question.

Comment: Oh, well, that's a horse of a different color! I (+1)'d @ssdecontrol's comment for the question, "How are you deciding that there is 'no risk separation whatsoever'?" Are you sure the effect isn't just falling short of a significance threshold (e.g., $\alpha = .05$)? This could result from the adjustment for multiple comparisons in a post hoc test. Doesn't seem like it should though, if shopping habits truly discriminates risk "quite well" among women, as you said...I'm a bit stumped too now (unless it's just calculation error somewhere), but I'll echo the recommendation to graph interactions!